# My laptop is unable to efficiently choose the right GPU

Tags: graphics-card

I have a HP Pavilion series laptop with the following specs:

- CPU: Ryzen 5 4500H
- GPU 1: AMD Radeon integrated
- GPU 2: Nvidia GTX 1650ti

The issue started suddenly. My laptop is not using the Nvidia GPU to its full potential. I used to get 130+ fps in CS:GO and Valorant, but now I'm getting around 60 fps. I saw that that my laptop has 100% AMD Radeon usage but only around 30% 1650ti usage. But in some games like Tomb Raider, my laptop is using 100% Nvidia GPU, and I am getting around 80 fps at high settings. I have already put Nvidia as the preferred graphics card in Nvidia settings. But there is no option for switchable graphics in the AMD Radeon software. I have also changed my power plan to prefer Nvidia graphics card.

Comment: Did you change drivers, or have you tried updating your GPU drivers?

Comment: I have updated all drivers

Comment: What is the make/model of your laptop?

Comment: Hp pavilion gaming laptop 15-ec1xxx